# Generics: I'm not quite sure what the <T> does - can you explain?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, .net-3.5

I'm creating an abstract class to derive from. I have a `Value` property that can be numerous data types. I saw an article on generics and I'm just wondering if my understanding is correct.

Does having an abstract:

```
BaseClass<T>
```

and inheriting it like:

```
InheritingClass: BaseClass<int>
```

basically equate to: *anywhere there is a type `T` defined in BaseClass , treat it as a type `int` when used through InheritingClass*?

That is my understanding and I just want to make sure that is correct before I build the rest of these classes and find out I was way off. This is the first time I've used generics.

Comment: If you've never used generics, you can read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx); it's a bit large, but very readable as MSDN articles go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anywhere there is a type T in InheritingClass , treat it as a type int

As already mentioned by @BoltClock, this is not the case.  I wonder, however, if you meant to say:

> anywhere there is a type T in BaseClass, treat it as a type int

If this is what you meant, then you are indeed correct.

Comment: Nice catch. I'm not sure why I hadn't thought of it myself.

Comment: Yah, I meant wherever there was a T in BaseClass, it will be treated as an int when inherited that way. So, when you use a property of type T defined in BaseClass through InheritedClass, it'd be an int.

Comment: @Yatrix: In that case, you should probably either edit your question (and I'll edit mine), or accept Kevin's answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not; it means your class specifically only inherits from `BaseClass<int>`. If you define a generic type parameter `T` in your `InheritingClass`, like this:

```
InheritingClass<T> : BaseClass<int>
```

Then that type parameter pertains only to `InheritingClass` and its own members, and does not apply to `BaseClass` in any way. Neither does `T` in `InheritingClass` automatically resolve to `int` due to the parentage. In other words, the two type parameters are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are for having type-safe classes that can be easily customized to be used with any type.  The "T" is a placeholder for the type you want to use with that class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

"Generics allow you to define type-safe data structures, without committing to actual data types."